# Where should I declare my private class level static constant in the header file?

Tags: c++, static-members

Where should I specify my class level static constant in the header file?

```
class ABC
{
public:
    enum A1
    {
    };

    //Manager functions
    ABC(int x )
    {
        m_x = x;
    };
    viirtual ~ABC();

protected:
    int data;

private:
    //Typedef
    typedef std::pair(int, int) INT_PAIR;
    typedef std::pair(int, int) INT_PAIR1;
    ...
    //functions
    void increment_x();
    //Member data
    int m_x;
    ... whole lot of other data
}
```

Where should I declare a private static const variable like version number inside this class declaration (ABC.h)?

```
static const std::string version;
```

Where exactly would it fit in? It is not really member data, since it is static. (not per object)

Edit - 1 :

Is there a specific precedence for these variables? Do they go at the start (right after the first opening curly brace after class ABC? Or right after the private keyword in my snippet? (OR) is it after the typedefs?

Of course I'll mention in my abc.cpp file that
   const std::string version = "10";

Edit 2:
I was expecting answers like what Lucas mentions.(please provide valid reasoning)

Where, inside a class declaration like the one I mentioned below, should the static variables be placed?

Please do not provide answers that mention that the decl needs to be in .h file and definition in .cpp file. – I know that already.

Comment: Put the _declaration_ in any private access area; put the _definition_ into a single source file, not a header.

Comment: Put it as the first class member or as last to you find it more easily.

Comment: @LucasNunes : I was expecting answers on these lines. Like the other answers mentioned I already know that the decl needs to be in .h file and definiton in.cpp file.

Answer (score 5):

A.h file (header:)

```
class A {
...
private:
    static const std::string version ;
} ;
```

A.cpp file (body, remember about `#include "A.h"` :)

```
const std::string A::version = "10" ;
```